# how to describe the three stages of before making policy, policy draft release and policy implementation?

Tags: word-usage, construction

I want to classify the process of creating a policy into three stages:

Step 1:  public begins to talk about an agenda, which attracts the government's attention.

Step 2:  the government releases a policy draft.

Step 3:  the policy comes into force.

I want to describe the process by three words. How about "pre-release" stage, "peri-release" stage, "post-release" stage?

Answer (score 1):

One would normally use pre-release and post-release to describe stages such as these, with the reference point being the date of effect. So here Steps 1 and 2 are both pre-release, and Step 3 is post release as the date of effect is when the policy comes into force.

Step 2 can also be referred to as the *draft* stage. *Draft* indicates that it is not an official release.

*Peri-release* is not a term that would be understood to mean the period of Step 2.

So:
Step 1 could be *discussion* (also *pre-release*) stage.
Step 2 could be *draft*  (also *pre-release*) stage.
Step 3 could be *release* (also *post-release*) stage.

Comment: In fact, I want to describe the Stage 2, when the government release the "Interim Measures for ....". May be this is not a draft, it is not yet come into force.  If in this case, can I use peri-release to describe Stage 2?

Comment: @cindy -- "[Peri](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/peri_2)" is not a commonly used prefix in English.  Most native speakers of English will not understand it.